# gcloud deploy fails nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy to google app engine. When I do so, the initial information all seems correct, the docker build is successful, but after docker it tries the following and fails:

```
Beginning teardown of remote build environment (this may take a few seconds).
Updating module [default].../Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/jamsesh-1219/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20160213t114355].
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
```

I know that I'm running es6 code transpiled to run on node 4.1.2 which is the version I'm told I can use [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features) - I just have to run `nvm install v4.1.2` which will switch me over, so I include that in my scripts. Here are my scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "test",
    "clean": "rm -rf lib",
    "watch-js": "./node_modules/.bin/babel --plugins transform-es2015-classes src --presets react -d lib",
    "dev-server": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack lib/client/entry.js",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./src",
    "server": "node lib/server/server",
    "start-dev": "npm run lint && npm run build && npm run dev-server && npm run server",
    "start": "nvm install v4.1.2 && node lib/server/server",
    "styles": "./node_modules/.bin/lessc ./public/less/bundle.less ./public/css/bundle.css",
    "build": "npm run clean && ./node_modules/.bin/babel --plugins transform-es2015-classes src --presets react -d lib && npm run styles"
  },
```

and my docker file:

```
# Dockerfile extending the generic Node image with application files for a
# single application.
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
COPY . /app/
# You have to specify "--unsafe-perm" with npm install
# when running as root.  Failing to do this can cause
# install to appear to succeed even if a preinstall
# script fails, and may have other adverse consequences
# as well.
# This command will also cat the npm-debug.log file after the
# build, if it exists.
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm || \
  ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then \
  cat npm-debug.log; \
fi) && false)
CMD npm start
```

So yeah, I've got no clue why the deployment failing. I could definitely benefit from some more thorough documentation on deploying node on GAE. It works on a test repo. Is there something else I need to be doing to run node on GAE with my babel6 transpiled code? Or should something be different in my scripts? In the Google Shell I can run locally fine once I switch to node v4.1.2

Comment: I abandoned GAE for Digital Ocean because GAE just had more things than I needed and wasn't working.

Comment: As Digital Ocean is an IaaS the equivalent Google service is Compute Engine which gives you full virtual machine instances. You may still be interested in comparing the services at https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing.

Comment: No thoughts on the actual issue with at hand?